# C++: invalid use of 'void'

Tags: c++

This code should print i = 35 as result but somehow it doesn't even compile. Why ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void increment(int &p){
    p = p +10;
}
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    increment(i) += 15;
    cout<<"i = " <<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this: `increment(i) += 15;`

Comment: Does this actually compile? `increment` is `void` so how can it be an lvalue?

Comment: An `lvalue` can be considered as a location.  When you assign values, the *left* side of the assignment operator needs to be a location.  Your function is not a location.

Comment: Think a little while... What does the `increment` function return?

Comment: Change to `int &increment(int &p){    p = p +10;
    return p;
}`

Comment: g++: error: invalid use of 'void'

Comment: *this code should print i = 35*... Not in C or C++ :)

Comment: I'd guess from the question title that it doesn't compile and the error message is pointing out an lvalue is required.

Comment: Also, please don't spam with unrelated language tags. If you program in C++ then only use the C++ tag. C and C++ are two very different languages.

Comment: Thank you  guys :)

Answer (score 4):

No it shouldn't! `increment` has `void` as return type, that means that an expression call to this function has no value. If you want that call to be able to be used on the left part of an assignment, it must return a left-value.

Basically, when you write `a=b` `a` denotes a container but `b` a value.

You can try:

```
int &increment(int &p){
    p = p +10;
    return p; // return the reference passed as argument...
}
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    increment(i) += 15;
    cout<<"i = " <<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```